# How remind password for mysql localhost base at Linux Mint?

Tags: mysql, bash, python-3.5, linux-mint, mysql-error-1045

I have a little confusing problem. Trying to connect into own localhost sql database. But always got an error with 1045 code:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): 
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Pycode:

```
config = {
    'user': 'root', #Tried our username and empty
    'password': '', #Tried few always used for learning, empty, and bruteforce with all isalnum letters from secound writed program with connector.Error catcher :P [to twelve string length].
    'host': '127.0.0.1', #Tried localhost / Guazowy(from mysql status)
    'database': 'outlet_refactor',
    'raise_on_warnings': True, #Without this also.
    }
serw = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

Also i tryied use other user, other host and passwords, maybe i once set password but forgot these. (I want to learn build database with python, but this problem for start is too enough for me. Over week i trying find solution)

Console send me that same error when try:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Mine mysql serwer is started when i check with:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Output:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since wto 2017-05-30 17:44:08 CEST; 1h 57min ago
  Process: 15834 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 15823 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15833 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─15833 /usr/sbin/mysqld

maj 30 17:44:07 Guazowy systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
maj 30 17:44:08 Guazowy systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Restart too isn't help
    sudo service mysql stop
    sudo service mysql start

Even i belive for dpkg to reconfigure/reset password (i tryied, but this is not for this).

I not have temporary generated password from 'MySQL Yum repository, MySQL SUSE repository, or RPM packages directly downloaded from Oracle', so

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysql.log #File not exist
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

doesn't print anythink, when I checking manually, just confirm grep results.

```
mysqladmin variables | grep socket #so grep port too isn't working
>>Out:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'guaz'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

Also i tryied few other methods in similar questions, but no one help with mine problem and now i can't find these. I'll be gratefull for help or any tips to solution :).

Comment: I throw there all what i try, becouse maybe some be helpfull for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the followin command:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORDHERE
```

As example:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root password 123456
```

to test if that is working:

```
$ mysql -u root -p'123456' -e 'show databases;'
```

To change your user password:

Conect from terminal to mysql with root:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Go to table mysql:

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

Change user password:

```
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("123456") where User='guaz';
```

Flush privilegies:

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Comment: mysqladmin still respond: mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'guaz'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: @Guaz Okey, after update the root password, update your user password like this, I updated the answer

Comment: Maybe this would help, but I don't know where i got table mysql, becouse even in root account after use comand 'su' and 'mysql -u root -p' mine term print that same error.

Comment: In that case, as I don't know what is happening really, I recommend that uninstall and reainstall from the term the Mysql server, but carefully, in one moment it will ask to you to put de root password, usually people use "root" as password of "root"

Comment: I think that really is a good solution, and takes a few minutes, then, after install properly mysql (without sudo su, please, not mandatory at all), you can run the commands I suggest to you

Comment: @Guaz to remove mysql follow this steps https://askubuntu.com/questions/776845/uninstall-mysql-from-ubuntu-16-04 puting your actual version of course

Comment: @Guaz let me know how it goes for you please!